# logging.path to ${LOG_PATH}

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I am setup to use logback with my SpringBoot application and everything is running fine and dandy.

I noticed a property called `logging.path` in the application.properties file which sets the value for `${LOG_PATH}` in logback.xml. How does it do it?

- I went through the [SpringBoot logging documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html).
- Any documentation I could find on [property placeholder configurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)

Yet I don't understand how `logging.path` could pass the value for `${LOG_PATH}`. Though not a killer issue, I would like to know how this mapping is made.

Comment: I bet LOG_PATH is an environment variable.

Comment: If it was an environment variable, how would it pick up the changes I make in the properties file?

Comment: I am sorry, I think I read your question backward. You have logging.path setting LOG_PATH, right?

Comment: Yes, `logging.path` in application.properties sets `${LOG_PATH}` in logback.xml

Answer (score 2):

The magic is spring will transfter `logging.path` into System propeties `LOG_PATH`.

Description from spring doc:

> To help with the customization some other properties are transferred from the Spring Environment to System properties:

And it also says:

> All the logging systems supported can consult System properties when parsing their configuration files. See the default configurations in spring-boot.jar for examples.

Details:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-configuration

For more recent versions of Spring Boot, [such as 2.5.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/htmlsingle/#features.logging.custom-log-configuration), the `logging.file.path` maps to `LOG_PATH`.